# How do I pull a Row from an Array in Google apps script Google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

My spreadsheet is composed of a main sheet that is populated using a form plus several other sheets for the people who work with the responses submitted through the form. A script delegates the form responses to these other sheets depending on the type of item described in the response.
The problem is, when Person A deletes an item from their respective sheet, it doesn't delete in the main sheet.
My idea is that when you type a set password into the corresponding cell in row 'Q' in Person A's sheet, it matches the item by timestamp to the original form submission and deletes both the version of the item in Person A's sheet as well as the main sheet. However, I can't figure out what to set the range to to get it to point to the row in the array. Everything I have tried has sent back "undefined" in the debugger and won't delete anything. I think the problem is that I don't know how to get the row from the array that I have made. See my code below:

```
   function onEdit() {//copies edited items from individual selector sheets back onto main spreadsheet

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var actSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var responseSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Item Request");
    var actCell = actSheet.getActiveCell();
    var actRow = actCell.getRow();
    var actVal = actCell.getValue();
    var actLoc = actCell.getA1Notation();
    var last = actSheet.getLastRow();
    var respLast = responseSheet.getLastRow();
    var dataA = responseSheet.getRange(1, 1, respLast, 1).getValues(); //compiles an array of data found in column A through last row in response sheet
    var tstamp1 = actSheet.getRange(actCell.getRow(), 1);
    var tsVal1 = tstamp1.getValue();
    var colEdit = actCell.getColumn();

    //===========THIS IS WHERE I'M STUCK=======================
 if ((actVal == "p@ssword") && (colEdit == 17)) {
      for (i = 1; i < dataA.length; i++) {
       if (dataA[i][0].toString == tsVal1.toString()) { 
         responseSheet.deleteRow(i + 1);
         actSheet.deleteRow(actRow);
         break;
       }
      }
    }

       else if (colEdit == 15) { //checks the array to see if the edit was made to the "O" column

            for (i = 1; i < dataA.length; i++) {//checking for timestamp match and copies entry 
                if (dataA[i][0].toString() == tsVal1.toString()) {
                    var toEdit = responseSheet.getRange(i + 1, 16);
                    toEdit.setValue(actVal);
                }
            }
       } 

     else if (colEdit == 16) { // checks the array to see if the edit was made in the "P" column

         for (i = 1; i < dataA.length; i++) {//checking for timestamp match and copies entry
             if (dataA[i][0].toString() == tsVal1.toString()) {
                var toEdit = responseSheet.getRange(i + 1, 17);
                toEdit.setValue(actVal);
             }
         }
     }  

    else {return;}
}//end onEdit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe these are proper commands `delRow.deleteRow();actCell.deleteRow();` Take a look at the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet);

Okay I rewrote that function for you a bit but I'm stilling wondering about a couple of lines.

```
function onEdit(e) 
{
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var actSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var responseSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Item Request");
    var actCell = actSheet.getActiveCell();
    var actRow = actCell.getRow();
    var actVal = actCell.getValue();
    var colEdit = actCell.getColumn();
    var respLast = responseSheet.getLastRow();
    var dataA = responseSheet.getRange(1, 1, respLast, 1).getValues(); 
    var tstamp1 = actSheet.getRange(actRow, 1);
    var tsVal1 = tstamp1.getValue();

    for(var i=0;i<dataA.length;i++)
    {
      if(new Date(dataA[i][0]).valueOf()==new Date(tsVal1).valueOf()) 
      { 
        if (actVal=="p@ssword" && colEdit==17) 
        {
          responseSheet.deleteRow(i + 1);
          actSheet.deleteRow(actRow);     
        }
        else if(colEdit==15) 
        { 
          var toEdit = responseSheet.getRange(i + 1, 16);//?
          toEdit.setValue(actVal);//?
        } 
        else if (colEdit == 16) 
        {
          var toEdit = responseSheet.getRange(i + 1, 17);//?
          toEdit.setValue(actVal);//?
        }  
      }
    }  
}
```

Can you explain the function of the lines with question marked comments?

Comment: Hello, I believe that I have fixed it. However, my problem now is getting the row from the array gathered in the for loop. Any ideas on that?

Comment: Perhaps you've fixed and not changed your question.  But in these two rows toEdit is not defined. `//var toEdit = responseSheet.getRange(); <---not sure how to point this back to the range I got from the array to mark that I want to delete the whole row
         responseSheet.deleteRow(toEdit);`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? The part I have commented out is the line that I do not know how to write correctly to point back to the row in the array.

Comment: Sorry, sometimes it's hard for me to change contexts.  But I looked at that area and I changed it in your question area to what I think makes sense.  Now I'm wondering about the rest of those toEdits because that particular one just needed to be a row number. It looks the range for data was row 1 , column 1, responseSheet.getLastRow() so I think it should be i + 1.

Comment: Yes! That makes sense. I copied it into my script, however, It still doesn't delete from either of my sheets for some reason?

Comment: SOLVED! It was missing a set of parentheses after the data[i][0].toString() <-- your above script worked perfectly. Thank you!